# create unique primary key in IBM netezza sql server ?

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, netezza

I need to create a unique primary key that can also be indexed in IBM netezza sql server ?

I find that netezza does not support UNIQUE key.

Are there some ways to get around this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649297/how-to-overcome-netezzas-lack-of-unique-constraint-referential-integrity-enforc

Comment: Netezza does not implement indexes at all, so what you mean by "indexed in IBM Netezza" is unclear.

Comment: Index is supported in netezza,  but, unique primary key is not supported. thanks

Comment: @BillProvince, that post does not solve the problem.

Comment: That is not correct. Netezza absolutely does not support the creation of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

IBM's PureData System for Analytics (aka Netezza) offers Sequences when you need to do something like create values for a surrogate key.

You can read [the documentation for sequences here.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_sequences.html)