# How can I create an ID column randomly, without repeating integers?

Tags: sql, sas, netezza, aginity

Suppose I have a table called `sourcetable` with `colA`, `colB`, `colC`. I simply want to create an id column with non-repeating, unique, and random integers. How can I create this either in netezza SQL or using proc SQL (SAS)?

Answer (score 1):

To ensure uniqueness you will certainly constrain `id` as either primary key or unique.

The SAS functions `UUIDGEN` or `RANUNI` are candidates for generating values with very high probability of uniqueness at computation time.  I don't think there is any simple/isolated function that can guarantee 100% it will not compute a value previously returned.

`UUIDGEN` returns a 36 byte character value such as `170bf2ef-16c7-4b7f-b25b-000333d9679b`

`RANUNI` scaled by by 1E15 will return an integer value with up to 14 digits.

```
data want;
  do i = 1 to 100;
    id_v1 = uuidgen();
    id_v2 = floor(1e15 * ranuni(0));
    output;
  end;
  format id_v2 15.;
run;
```

For Netezza try a look at SO [How to overcome Netezza's lack of unique constraint/referential integrity enforcement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649297/how-to-overcome-netezzas-lack-of-unique-constraint-referential-integrity-enforc)
"

Comment: How can this be done using proc sql? My data set is over 2 billion records and I need to write this code with sql

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use a serial number returned from a sequence ?  Sounds more like a question for Netezza experts if you have 2B records Netezza side.  Not sure how you get such a large table in a presumed DW without a unique row identifier already baked into the design